# Is it good to make methods return 'self' for chaining method calls?

Tags: python, memory-management, method-chaining, function-call

I have a class, for example:

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    def add(self):
        self.x += 1
        return self
```

If I want to chain methods, I can use:

```
my_example = Example()
my = my_example.add().add().add().add().add().add()
# Use 'my' later on and modify and so on...
```

Will it consume more and more memory whenever I use `add()` or something ?

I want to build a library with method chaining functionality, but just wondering is this good ?

Comment: No, it won't use any more memory, it's just a reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't consume more memory because `self` is a reference to the same object.

"Is this good?" - depends on the functionality you want. If you want to modify the existing object, then it should be fine.